# Views on puranas as texts to be taken literally or metaphorically?

Tags: puranas

Are the story of puranas merely used as icons(to teach us lessons)?
Are they to be taken literally?Do they fall under smriti or sruti?

Comment: Same as are-mythologies-real-historical-or-merely-allegorical

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33024/are-mythologies-real-historical-or-merely-allegorical