# Are things written in Hindu texts factually incorrect ? I think so

Tags: mahabharata, puranas

Just to make it clear the things written in Hindu texts have huge amount of knowledge in them and I have learnt a lot about life and philosophy from them.
But I think the things written in Hindu texts are factually incorrect and have been written for people to learn some life lessons and learn philosophy. The reasons are -

1. No Archaeological or physical evidence at all whatsoever of stories written like - Mahabharata , Ramayana or stories written in Puranas.
2. Archaeological evidence that is available in against the Hindu texts like - Excavations done in India have revealed Human civilization to as back as 7500 BC. But not a single Hindu symbol has been found in them.
3. Why supernatural things happen only in the past ? Why  don't they happen in present ? For example why are there no superhuman people like Bhima , Arjun etc today ?
4. Gods and Devtas used to frequently appear infront of common people in the past (according to Hindu texts) . Why don't they appear now ? Why do they hide today ?
5. Why Vishnu never incarnated in Shudra caste ? He incarnated in Yadav caste but only when Yadavs were in the role of Kings at that time period.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are mythologies real (historical) or merely allegorical?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33024/are-mythologies-real-historical-or-merely-allegorical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not an archaeologist. Here are the links where you can read about what real archaeologists say about Ramayana and Mahabharata. Both these guys are very famous archaeologists and need no introduction. But still, in case, you do not know, S. R. Rao was a marine archaeologist who found the remnants of the lost city of Dwarka. B. B. Lal served as the director of the Archaeological Survey of India (ASI).

[Rama: His Historicity, Mandir and Setu, Evidence of Literature, and Archaeology by B. B. Lal](https://www.amazon.in/Rama-Historicity-Evidence-Literature-Archaeology/dp/8173053456/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=Rama%20setu&qid=1611335791&s=books&sr=1-3)

[The Lost City of Dwarka by S. R. Rao](https://www.amazon.in/Lost-City-Dwarka-S-Rao/dp/8186471480)

[Historicity of the Mahabharata: Evidence of Literature, Art and Archaeology by B. B. Lal](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/8173054584/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_hsch_vapi_taft_p1_i4)

Answer (score 2):

Your assertions are incorrect. There are several well documented evidences to refute your assumptions. Let me answer them one by one.

Please read following for scientific analysis with archeological, astronomical and geographical artifacts on Ramayan, Mahabharat etc. Recall that Saraswati was sold as mythical river just couple of generations ago. We have clear proofs of not only its existence but complete path and reasons for its degradation.

1. [Ramayan Retold with Scientific Evidences - Saroj Bala](https://garudabooks.com/ramayan-retold-with-scientific-evidences)
2. [Mahabharat: RETOLD WITH SCIENTIFIC EVIDENCE - Saroj Bala](https://garudabooks.com/mahabharat-retold-with-scientific-evidence)
3. [The Lost River - Michel Danino](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Lost_River/8yc7-OirxKEC?hl=en)

> No Archaeological or physical evidence at all whatsoever of stories written like - Mahabharata , Ramayana or stories written in Puranas.

Sh Ramkrishna Paramhans had pratyaksh darshan of Mata Kali multiple times. Some excerpts from [THE FIRST VISION OF KALI - The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/introduction/the_first_vision.htm)

> He has thus described his first vision of the Mother: "I felt as if my heart were being squeezed like a wet towel. I was overpowered with a great restlessness and a fear that it might not be my lot to realize Her in this life. I could not bear the separation from Her any longer. Life seemed to be not worth living. Suddenly my glance fell on the sword that was kept in the Mother's temple. I determined to put an end to my life. When I jumped up like a madman and seized it, suddenly the blessed Mother revealed Herself.
> The buildings with their different parts, the temple, and everything else vanished from my sight, leaving no trace whatsoever, and in their stead I saw a limitless, infinite, effulgent Ocean of Consciousness. As far as the eye could see, the shining billows were madly rushing at me from all sides with a terrific noise, to swallow me up! I was panting for breath. I was caught in the rush and collapsed, unconscious. What was happening in the outside world I did not know; but within me there was a steady flow of undiluted bliss, altogether new, and I felt the presence of the Divine Mother." On his lips when he regained consciousness of the world was the word "Mother".

Bottomline : there is lot to learn than what meets the eye.